# R: how can I read the cell references along with reading the data from Excel

Tags: r, excel

I have a data as below in excel where A-G  are excel columns and 1  -> row number, that i am reading into my code using read_excel.

```
  A       B       C      D       E     F          G
 India  France  Italy   USA     UK    Peru     Russia
```

is there a way to read it into a dataframe as:

```
India   A1 

France  B1

Italy   C1

USA     D1

UK      E1

Peru    F1

Russia  G1
```

Comment: If you read in a file that has two lines with the first row as column names and a single line of data then the `unlist` function applied to the resulting data frame would give you a named vector with the letters as rownames and the country names as values. Not exactly what you wanted but perhaps useful. If the data is more complex than a single row excel file then you should make your example data more complex as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the code general I have divided data into two rows. For example, if your data is like this :

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("India", "UK"), B = c("France", "Peru"), 
    C = c("Italy", "Russia"), D = c("USA", "Spain")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df
#      A      B      C     D
#1 India France  Italy   USA
#2    UK   Peru Russia Spain
```

You can get the data in long format and paste row number to column name for each column.

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(name = paste0(name, row_number()))

# name  value 
#  <chr> <chr> 
#1 A1    India 
#2 B1    France
#3 C1    Italy 
#4 D1    USA   
#5 A2    UK    
#6 B2    Peru  
#7 C2    Russia
#8 D2    Spain
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stack` from `base R`

```
stack(df)
# values ind
#1  India   A
#2     UK   A
#3 France   B
#4   Peru   B
#5  Italy   C
#6 Russia   C
#7    USA   D
#8  Spain   D
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("India", "UK"), B = c("France", "Peru"), 
    C = c("Italy", "Russia"), D = c("USA", "Spain")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```